# Identity client runtime library (idcrl) did not get a response from the login server

Tags: .net-core, sharepoint-online, clientcontext

I use SharePointOnline.Portable library for uploading files to sharepoint. Everything worked recently, but now I am struggling from an error "Identity Client Runtime Library (idcrl) did not get a response from the login server". I tried to use user without MFA, but unfortunately response was the same. All licenses are ok. Does someone know any reasons why it can be caused?

using var clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);
clientContext.Credentials = new SharePointOnlineCredentials(userEmail, userPassword);

var webContext = clientContext.Web;
clientContext.Load(webContext, web => web.ServerRelativeUrl);

await clientContext.ExecuteQueryAsync(); // fails on this line

Comment: Mines just started doing this as well, did you have to set up an authentication string in your SharePoint Admin centre?

Comment: @squatman Where in the admin center is the "authentication string" configured? Suffering the same problem as OP.

Comment: @squatman, is it neccessarily to set up authentication string to make it work?

Comment: Apologies it wasn't an authentication string, it was an Application ID generated in https://portal.azure.com Azure Active Directory > App registrations and registering your own app to allow authentication. I haven't managed to solve my problem yet. The error occurs in my AuthenticationManager when trying to retrieve the Token, error "interaction_required" - "AADSTS50076: Due to a configuration change made by your administrator, or because you moved to a new location, you must use multi-factor authentication to access...". I've looked at what I can find with MFA and all seems to be as it should

Comment: I've read something about setting locations and that a flag may have been set to invalidate the location. I'll let you know if I find anything new or solve it. Please do the same as this is very frustrating. Thank you.

Comment: @squatman any progress here? Also receive **Connect-SPOService : Identity Client Runtime Library (IDCRL) did not get a response from the Login server.** and don't know what to do.

Comment: @MarTin this was a while ago now, I think it was all to do with MFA being enabled on my clients SharePoint. The only thing I've managed to do to get it working was to create a self-signed certificate in command prompt, register the App in Azure / Entra Portal, upload the certificate there and then update the authentication method in my App to point to the certificate.pfx location (each user does not need to install the cert, the app can point to it) Let me know if you want help with any of that. Sorry I only saw the notification email today of your comment.